# TypeError mocking express response object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, express, response, sinon

I'm currently trying to write a test using `sinon` and `sinon-express-mock` to mock an incorrect request and then call a validation function in my application, ensuring that the validation function returns the correct response status (400). However, currently I am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`. I thought `send` would be mocked along with the rest of the `res` object, but if not how can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

The function I am testing:

```
export const validateItemRequest = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.query.number) {
        return res.status(400).send('Number not specified');
    } else if ( req.query.number % 1 !== 0) {
        return res.status(400).send('Incorrect number syntax');
    } 
};
```

The test code:

```
describe('item', function() {

    it('should only accept valid requests', function() {

        const itemRequest = {
            query: {
                number: 'abcde',
            },
        };

        const req = mockReq(request);
        const res = mockRes();

        itemController.validateItemRequest(req, res);

    });
});
```

Comment: req.query.number % 1, when is modulus ever not 0?

Comment: @Bindrid when the number has a decimal place

Answer (score 1):

`sinon-express-mock` currently does not support chaining. There's [an open issue to add chaining support](https://github.com/danawoodman/sinon-express-mock/issues/1), but the methods currently don't return the object making it impossible to chain from `res.status` to `send`.

I only needed a few of the response methods for my test, so I made my own response spy like this:

```
var response = {  
  status: sinon.spy(function() { return response; }),  
  send: sinon.spy(),  
  sendStatus: sinon.spy(),
  reset: function() {
    for (var method in this) {
      if (method !== 'reset') {
        this[method].reset();
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Notice I only return the response from `status` since you shouldn't chain off `send` and `sendStatus`.

Answer (score -1):

```
response = { 
   json:(obj) => { response.body = obj },
   status:function(status) {
     response.statusValue = status;
   return this;
 }
```